# Bootstrap: div inside li

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add `divs` to the list items of my `ul`, but this is causing the Twitter Bootstrap framework to behave weirdly. Is this because of something I am doing wrong, or is there a different solution for what I am trying to do?

The code:

```
<h3>Track listing</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="song-title">1. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="song-title">2. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="song-title">3. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS code:

```
.song-title {float: left;}
.song-duration {float: right;}
```

I am using the `float` attributes in an attempt to make each song's title appear on the left, and the durations on the right. From my (very limited) CSS experience, this should work.

The result:

[image]

I have the impression that the list items' sizes are not taking the `div` sizes in consideration, instead resizing as if they were completely empty.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

You can `clear:both` on the `li` to treat the `li` as a block level element.

(Add a `clearfix` on the `li`)

#### Track listing

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <div class="song-title">1. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <div class="song-title">2. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <div class="song-title">3. Song Title</div>
        <div class="song-duration">3:50</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuar4e7v/)

Comment: It works! Darn, I knew it would be this simple! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It pretty late to answer this question but I thought it will help some-one if they want to try alternative approach to the accepted solution.

I kept the structure in a container and set its `max-width` property to `100%`

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="container" style="max-width:100%">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```